# UIView size getting screwed when launching in Landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a containment `UIViewController` and in my `viewDidLoad` method I am loading its child view controller from the storyboard. Then I add the child view controllers view as a sub view and try to set this new views size:

```
  childVC.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,768,1004);
```

What happens is that when you start the app in Landscape mode, you get a 20px "gap" at the left side (bottom side of the physical device).
I can avoid this if I get the device orientation in my code and use

```
  CGRectMake(0,0,748,1024);
```

for the frame property instead when landscape is detected. However, I think there must be a different solution.

Before the question comes up: I set the frame instead of the bounds property because once this problem is solved I need to position the view somewhere else than 0,0. As far as I know there's no other way to do this, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the child view's frame based on the parent view's bounds. Then be sure that the child view's autoresizing mask is set to both "flexible width" and "flexible height". Don't hardcode sizes like you are.

```
childVC.view.frame = parentVC.view.bounds;
childVC.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Once this works, you can tweak the child view's frame as needed. But it still should be based on the parent view's bounds.

Comment: That makes sense. So is it right that for example, when you add a view with 500px width combined with `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`; the outcome absolutely depends on whether the device is currently in landscape or portait mode?

E.g. device is in portrait mode when view is loaded: 500px in portrait mode, 666px in landscape mode
vs
device is in landscape mode when view is loaded: 500px in landscape mode, 375px in portrait mode

Comment: When you set the child view's resizing mask to "flexible width", then the child view's width will automatically adjust when its parent view's width changes (for any reason). If the parent gets bigger, the child gets bigger. If the parent gets smaller, the child gets smaller.